# How do you attach swf file to separate buttons to play in seperate window

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am new here so please have patience with me.

What I am doing is making a portfolio. On one layer I have 6 buttons to 6 separate swf files. I am trying to add a click event to open and close each file when button is clicked. The following code allows me to click on one button and not be able to close it, as well as it takes up the portfolio swf and will not close or allow me to click another button for a different swf file.

Here is the code that is close to what I need I think. It's been a while since I used Actionscript and I can't remember how to get the results that I am looking for.

Please help I am using trial right now for cs6 and will run out soon. The older Flash I have doesn't have the functions I need.

```
var loadedSWF:Loader = null;

function loadSWF(file:String, container:MovieClip=null):void
{
    if(container == null) container = MovieClip(root);

    if(loadedSWF != null)
    {
        if(loadedSWF.parent) loadedSWF.parent.removeChild(loadedSWF);
    }

    var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(file);
    loadedSWF = new Loader();
    loadedSWF.load(req);

    addChild(loadedSWF);
}

cars.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _click);

function _click(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    loadSWF("cars.swf");
}
```

Comment: Hi coffwen, welcome to SO. (Check out http://www.stackoverflow.com/help for some community rules. Very important!) Good first question, but I need some more info in the question: what is your SPECIFIC problem, and what have you tried?

Comment: the code I stipulated is the closest that I have been able to get to work. I have a Flash file that has 6 buttons that have an swf with each of them. I am trying to get each swf file to play when button is clicked. As well as open in separate window instead of the same window. This line of code doesn't allow me to close the swf file that is playing either. Basically they would click on the pic of the file and the swf would play in seperate windoew and close when viewing is done. I need to do this for 6 seperate buttons. I hope this makes sense

Comment: I don't work with external SWF files a lot, so I'll let someone else properly answer. However, I will say that (in general), it is easier to work with nested MovieClips, swapping them out on your stage, rather than loading different .swf files. However, I don't know your project, so that's just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modularize the code, so that you can use multiple instances of it. To do this you need to convert it into a real class instead of a framescript that is secretly moved into the class for the timeline it is on.

To make layout easy, you should link the new class to a movieclip symbol and place that on the timeline.